# $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is co-hopfian

Tags: gr.group-theory

Is it true that $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is co-hopfian for $n \geq 3$? I heard about this result, but I can't find any reference. Would be grateful for any references!

Comment: Reminder: co-hopfian means: every injective endomorphism is surjective.

Comment: I bet one could make a fairly elementary argument, without using superrigidity or CSP. The upper nilpotent subgroup should map to a nilpotent subgroup, which ought to allow you to pin it down inside $SL_n\mathbb{Z}$ as a subgroup of an upper triangular group up to conjugation. Then one can probably show that the matrices in $SL_{n-1}\mathbb{Z} \ltimes \mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$ map identically, using the fact that the linear action of $SL_{n-1}\mathbb{Z}$ is determined by the action on the upper triangular $\mathbb{Z}^{n-1}$. Then these reps. can probably be assembled to show that it is a conjugation.

Answer (score 8):

Yes it's true. Indeed, denote it by $\Gamma$. Every injective endomorphism $f$ of $\Gamma$ extends ($*$), at least in restriction to some finite index subgroup $\Lambda$, to an automorphism of $G=\mathrm{SL}_n(\mathbf{R})$; fix a Haar measure for the latter.

The automorphism group of the latter is unimodular (since it has the finite index subgroup $\mathrm{PGL}_n(\mathbf{R})$ which has no nontrivial continuous homomorphism to $\mathbf{R}$), and hence maps $\Lambda$ to a subgroup of the same covolume. So $\Lambda$ and $f(\Lambda)$ have the same index in $\Gamma$. This implies that $\Gamma$ and $f(\Gamma)$ also have the same index in $\Gamma$, that is, $f(\Gamma)=\Gamma$.

($*$) is a particular instance of Margulis' superrigidity, but maybe was previously known. Also, maybe there is a more direct approach.

Comment: Thinking twice, I'm pretty sure that every injective endomorphism $f$ indeed extends to $G$ (no only in restriction to a finite index subgroup).

Comment: I know, that in Margulis superrigidity theorem we nead also the following condition: the image of the homomorphism $f: \Gamma \to \Gamma$ is dense in Zariski topology. Is it true in our case? Can you explain please why?

Comment: Yes we need Zariski-dense image, maybe. Indeed there's no homomorphism $\Gamma\to G$ with infinite non-Zariski-dense image. Indeed first it would be injective (or kernel of order 2) and hence the Zariski closure would virtually have a simple quotient of dimension $<\dim(G)$, and applying superrigidity at this level would yield a contradiction.

Comment: I have one more question... Why the extension of out injective endomorphism to $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ will be  necessary an automorphism?

Comment: @MariaGerasimova because an endomorphism of $SL_n(\mathbf{R})$ is either trivial or is an automorphism. Indeed, if nontrivial, by simplicity, the kernel is discrete, so since the target has the same dimension, it has to be surjective. Since the quotient by the 2-element center (for even $n$) is not isomorphic to the original group, the kernel has to be trivial.

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my comment due to the crucial mistake.

Comment: If I remember correctly, Raghunathan had some earlier version of Margulis' theorem for non-uniform irreducible lattices.

Comment: Does the same argument work for any lattice in semisimple Lie group of higher rank (for which Margulis superrigidity works)?

Comment: @MariaGerasimova yes, more precisely, for every irreducible lattice. Or, to be more general: take a lattice $\Gamma$ in a semisimple Lie group $G$ with no compact factor; then there is a unique almost direct decomposition $G=G_1\dots G_n$ such that $\Gamma\cap G_i$ is an irreducible lattice in $G_i$ -recall that irreducible means that the projection *modulo* any simple factor is dense- then the result holds when all $G_i$ (which are not necessarily simple) are assumed to be of real rank $\ge 2$, or even more generally when all $G_i$ satisfy superrigidity, which allows some rank 1 cases.

Comment: Illustrating example of my previous comment: $\Gamma=SL_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}]\times SL_5(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{3}])$, where $G=SL_2(\mathbf{R})\times SL_2(\mathbf{R})\times SL_5(\mathbf{R})\times SL_5(\mathbf{R})$, and $n=2$, $G_1=SL_2(\mathbf{R})\times SL_2(\mathbf{R})$, $G_2=SL_5(\mathbf{R})\times SL_5(\mathbf{R})$. Then $\Gamma$ is cohopfian as well as its finite index subgroups.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need superrigidity. A [completely elementary argument](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s24/sh/b44aadf7-897d-47d7-b0be-024464a1bc87/0df4a40e114c4873c7bc189c91248732) is given by Bob Steinberg in:

*Steinberg, Robert*, Some consequences of the elementary relations in $SL_n$, Finite groups - coming of age, Proc. CMS Conf., Montreal/Que. 1982, Contemp. Math. 45, 335-350 (1985). [ZBL0579.20038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0579.20038).

Comment: It's certainly simpler than Margulis' but certainly not "completely elementary": first, it relies on writing down a presentation (the "standard" K-theoretic one). Second, it relies on the congruence subgroup property (Theorem 3, for which the author indeed a proof that is simpler than any I knew before). Using this he gets the substitute for Margulis' superrigidity, namely a structural result for homomorphisms $SL_n(Z)\to GL_m(C)$ (Theorem 6). The proof takes 3 pages. Finally, one still needs some basic Lie theory (unimodularity of the automorphism group of $SL_n(R)$)...

Comment: @YCor Yes, "cpmpletely elementary" is an exaggeration, I agree...

Answer (score 3):

$\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is indeed cohopfian and evenmore, every *non-trivial* homomorphism $\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})\to \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})$ is onto,
and this could be seen in a fairly elementary fashion. 
My answer here should be seen as an extended comment to YCor's answer. For simplicity I will deal with the case $n=3$.

The following theorem, which elementary proof will be sketched below, is a version of "super-rigidity".

**Theorem:** Given a non trivial homomorphism $\phi:\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})\to \text{SL}_3(\mathbb{C})$ there exists a basis $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\mathbb{C}^3$ such  that the image of $\phi$ could be identified with the group of orientation preserving automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}v_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_3\in \mathbb{C}^3$.

The proof of the lemma relies only on the following fact concerning elementary matrices in $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$. Denote 
$$ U_1=\{E_{1,2}(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\},~ U_2=\{E_{1,3}(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\},~U_3=\{E_{2,3}(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\},~ $$
$$ U_4=\{E_{2,1}(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\},~U_5=\{E_{3,1}(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\},~U_6=\{E_{3,2}(t)\mid t\in\mathbb{Z}\}. $$
This 6 subgroups $U_i$ (with the standing convention $i\in\mathbb{Z}/(6)$) satisfy:

- they are all isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$,
- they are all conjugated in $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ (by the Weyl group).
- they sequentially commute, that is $[U_i,U_{i+1}]=1$.
- for all $i$, $U_i$ is the commutator group of $U_{i-1}$ and $U_{i+1}$, that is $[U_{i-1},U_{i+1}]=U_i$.
- together they generate $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$.

It follows that for every $i$, $H_i=\langle U_{i-1},U_{i+1}\rangle$ is an isomorphic copy of the discrete Heisenberg group $H$ whose center is given by $U_i$.
By the facts that the $U_i$'s generate and they are all conjugated, it must be that the non-trivial $\phi$ in the theorem is non-trivial on each of the ${U_i}$'s. Thus for every $i$, $\phi|_{H_i}$ is non-trivial on the center. This is useful because of the following lemma, which proof I leave as an exercise.

**Lemma:** Let $\psi:H\to \text{SL}_3(\mathbb{C})$ be a homomorphism which is non-trivial on the center. Then the image of the center is a rank-1 unipotent group (a group of operators $u$ which eigenvalues are all 1, and such that the image of $u-1$ is 1-dimensional).

Advice: when trying to follow my notation in the proof below, have in mind the case where $\phi$ is the standard representation.

*Sketch of the proof of the theorem:*
By the lemma, for every $i$, $\phi(U_i)$ is a rank-1 unipotent group. Denote by $P_i<\mathbb{C}^3$ the invariant plane of $\phi(U_i)$. By commutation, $P_i$ is preserved under $U_{i-1}$ and $U_{i+1}$. By the fact that $[U_{i-1},U_{i+1}]$ it is easy to see that either $P_{i-1}=P_i$ or $P_{i+1}=P_i$, but not both.
It follows that either 
$$ (1)~~P_1=P_2,~P_3=P_4,~P_5=P_6 \quad \text{or} \quad (2)~~P_1=P_6,~P_3=P_2,~P_5=P_4. $$ 
Note that applying inverse-transpose to $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ takes $U_i\to U_{i+3}$, so upon precomposing $\phi$ with inverse-transpose we may and will assume that option (2) occurs (as is the for the standard representation).
So we have these three planes $P_1,P_3,P_5$ and their three lines of intersection $L'_i=P_{i-1}\cap P_{i+1}$, $i=2,4,6$. For notational convenience it makes sense to denote $L_i=L'_{2i}$, $i=1,2,3$.

Reflecting on $\phi(H_2)$ it is easy to see that $L_1$ is the image of the rank one transformations in $\phi(U_1)-1$ and $\phi(U_2)-1$. Similarly, $L_2$ is the image of the rank one transformations in $\phi(U_3)-1$ and $\phi(U_4)-1$ and $L_3$ is the image of the rank one transformations in $\phi(U_5)-1$ and $\phi(U_6)-1$. Fix $0\neq v_1\in L_1$ and set $v_2 = (\phi(E_{2,1}(1))-1)v_1$ and $v_3 = (\phi(E_{3,2}(1))-1)v_1$ it is easy to check that coordinate change $e_1\mapsto v_i$ conjgates $\text{GL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$ to the group of automorphisms of the lattice $\mathbb{Z}v_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_3$.  $~~~\square$

The proof we gave above is constructive and actually gives more than demanded: for $i=1,2,3$ the lines $\mathbb{C}v_i$ are identified with the images of the rank-1 operators $\phi(E_{i,i-1}(1))-1$ and an arbitrary choice of $v_1\in \text{Im}(\phi(E_{1,3}(1))-1)$ determines uniquely the choices of $v_2$ and $v_3$ in the corresponding lines. For simplicity of formulation I did not put this into the theorem, but this is useful. For example, if $\phi:\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})\to \text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})<\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{C})$, it follows by the construction that the lines $L_i$ are rational, and upon choosing $v_1$ with integer coordinates, the vectors $v_i$ are integer. We get that $\mathbb{Z}v_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_3< \mathbb{Z}^3$. Finally, observe that for a full rank subgroup $\Lambda<\mathbb{Z}^3$, unless $\Lambda$ is charcteristic, there exists an orientation preserving automorphism of $\Lambda$ which does not extend to $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$.
Comparing with the theorem above, we conclude that $\mathbb{Z}v_1\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}v_3< \mathbb{Z}^3$ is characteristic and thus $\phi$ is onto $\text{SL}_3(\mathbb{Z})$.